# Updating Multiple HTML Fields into MySQL Database with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

This seems like a very basic task; I am not sure if I am having a brain cramp or if I ran into something a bit more rare.  But it doesn't seem so.

I have a table called `products` that have these columns:  `ID, Model, Cost, Quantity`

My HTML form prints out all price and quantity discounts by model; I loop thru like this:

```
 <form method="post">

 <table>
       <tr>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Pricing</th>
       </tr>

      <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>

       <tr>
           <td><?php echo $row['model']; ?></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['cost']; ?>" /></td>

      </tr>

     <?php } ?>

 </table>


  <input type="submit" name="retail_price" value="Update Pricing"  />

 </form>
```

So it prints out all pricing in text fields, and has a button so that there can be "mass" update to pricing.

My question is regarding the `PHP` where I am stuck:

```
if (isset($_POST['retail_price'])) {  // THIS CODE IS NOT COMPLETE!

    $query = "
        UPDATE retail_pricing
        SET pricing = {$new price}
                    WHERE id = {$id} ";
    mysqli_query($connection, $query);

}
```

The issue I have run into, I want to go through each field and update each one.  Doing a quick search for other Stack questions, it seems like I need to use a `foreach` to iterate through each field.  Is this correct?  Also, would the query be in the loop as well?

Comment: Why do you want to iterate over all the fields?  You can make one update with all the fields if they are in the same table.

Comment: I think the biggest thing I am struggling with is the identifying mark.  What to put in the `name=""` field.  It should be unique, but the ID doesn't seem like that is appropriate.  So on the `POST`, I'd have to manually spell out each field and since I am looping through the fields to create them in `HTML`, seemed like I would need to do the same on the `php` end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if(is_numeric($key))
    {
        $query = "UPDATE retail_pricing SET pricing = $value  WHERE id = $key ";
        mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    }  
}
```

Comment: It will most likely work, but this will also accept any numeric field name even if it is not a valid ID in your DB, which may cause failures.

Comment: @Sébastien Ok thanks, good to know.  This is  avery, very simply project so I'll stick with it since it's not broke, but going forward I would be inclined to use yours; so I upvoted as well.

Comment: As long as you are aware of it :)

Answer (score 2):

Add a hidden input in your HTML that will collect all IDs:

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['model']; ?></td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['cost']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ids[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

then when you submit the form you can loop through all those IDs and update you DB:

```
foreach( $_POST['ids'] as $id )
{
    $price = $_POST[$id];
     $query = "
        UPDATE retail_pricing
        SET pricing = {$price}
                    WHERE id = {$id} ";
    mysqli_query($connection, $query);
}
```

Comment: I prefer this method as it will prevent any issues with the query if you add further form fields in the future.